# Sending push notification toast to windows phone using Parse api through php web services

Tags: php, windows-phone-8, parse-platform

I need to send push messages from my web service to the windows phone. I am able to achieve this from console, however i need to do this using a php script

Code i have tried:

```
    $url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/push';

$appId = 'xxx';
$restKey = 'xxx';



$push_payload = json_encode(array(
        "where" => '"deviceType"=>"winrt"',
        "data" => array(
                "alert" => "This is the alert text."
        )
));

$rest = curl_init();
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_PORT,443);
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$push_payload);
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
        array("X-Parse-Application-Id: " . $appId,
                "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: " . $restKey,
                "Content-Type: application/json"));
                $response = curl_exec($rest);
                echo $response;
                var_dump($response);
    }
```

But on the dumping the response i get a boolean value:false and no notification appears on the phone.

Comment: Have you take a look at the Parse SDK?
https://parse.com/docs/php/guide#push-notifications-sending-pushes
https://github.com/parseplatform/parse-php-sdk

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$push_payload = json_encode(array(
    "where" => array("deviceType" => "winrt"),     
    "data"  => array("alert" => "This is the alert text.")
));
```